# Expected response code 354 but got code "503", with message "503 5.5.1 RCPT first. w15sm3670747wrs.80 - gsmtp "

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, smtp, gmail

I am using Laravel 5.8 and I am trying to send email from system using below setting.
when is send email one by one its working fine but when I send bunch of marketing email together it stopped after sending 20 email and giving me below error.

I am using below setting in .env.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=my user name
MAIL_PASSWORD=my gmail app password
```

I am getting below error after sending 20 emails

```
Expected response code 354 but got code "503", with message "503 5.5.1 RCPT first. w15sm3670747wrs.80 - gsmtp "
```

**also I tried with TLS but it's giving me same error after 20 emails...**

Comment: Facing same issue. Did you find any answer?

Comment: @TariqMahmood added answer, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All email senders have a limit of how many emails can be sent in a particular second.
Amazon's SES, for example, has limit of 40 emails per second.

I am using this logic to solve this issue:

```php
$count = 0;
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $count++;
    $user->notify(
        (new Notification($emailBody))
            ->delay(intdiv($count,30))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a bug where you are sending a DATA command without first sending a valid RCPT TO command.  That might mean that none of your RCPT TO commands were accepted by the server.  I suggest tracing the entire SMTP conversation so you can see how that might be happening.