# Laravel: Expected response code 354 but got code \"503\", with message \"503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error

Tags: php, laravel

The Laravel `mail()` function works OK when I send emails to Gmail accounts from my company mail (sales@stopshoprei.com). But When I send it to my own company email domain accounts like 'info@360synergytech.com' from the same mail (sales@stopshoprei.com) it gives the error.

> (Expected response code 354 but got code "503", with message
> "503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:\r\n503-No Such
> User Here\r\n503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA\r\n"",).

**Controller**

```
public function mailSenderIntegration(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->input();
    $crm_payment = CrmPayment::where('unique_Id', $data["unique_Id"])->first();
    //data for client mail
    $firstName = $crm_payment->first_name;
    $services_choosed = $crm_payment->requested_services;
    $services_choosed = json_decode($services_choosed);
    $count_services = count($services_choosed);
    $client_email = $crm_payment->email;

    $mailData = [
        'name' => $firstName,
        'body' => "There's an integration you need which is not listed at 
            futureflippercrm.stopshoprei.com.
            Our sales person would contact you soon for requirements.",
    ];
    
    //Mail client
    Mail::to($client_email)
        ->send(new mailTempInt($mailData));
}
```

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.stopshoprei.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=sales@stopshoprei.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=sales@stopshoprei.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Future Flipper CRM"
```

I tried to change port but same result. Is this an issue with domain?

Comment: `No Such User Here` seems important...

Comment: Did you check this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53703883/laravel-mail-sending-through-smtp-server-error-503-5-5-2

Comment: Yes i tried but still no luck

Comment: Please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101995/expected-response-code-354-but-got-code-503-with-message-503-5-5-1-rcpt-firs

Comment: I am only sending one email. Its working alright with Yahoo, Gmail and hotmail. But not with my company mails.